# Boolean values return false always

Tags: android, android-edittext, boolean

I am trying to check if my email is match email type and if my password length is more than 0 so I have used boolean to check that but that looks bad idea I think because it always return false and couldn't change the value to true here's my java code:

```
private boolean mEmail_Correct = false;
private boolean mPass_Correct = false;

mEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(s.toString()).matches()){mEmail_Correct = true;}
        else {mEmail_Correct = false;}}});

mPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.lenght>0){mPass_Correct = true;}
        else {mPass_Correct = false;}}});

if (mEmail_Correct && mPass_Correct){}//I need to make sign in btn light
else {}//I need to make sign in btn dim/faint

//But nothing happen so what can i use instead of private booleans
```

Both of booleans return false so is there any way to change the value for the boolean to true I think mEmail_Correct = true; doesn't work fine.

Comment: rather check password length email type on button click and type can't you perform this operation on button click..?

Comment: I need this method auto so I don't want it with button click I actuality need it like instagram login activity.

Comment: `mEmail_Correct` and `mPass_Correct` will always be `false` if you check them there. You need to check them after the user enters something in one of the fields. The code executes the listeners and then immediately goes on with the rest of the code, which is your check. Could this be your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can trigger a function that does the work you want depending on the user if he enters the email and password correctly

```
private boolean mEmail_Correct = false;
private boolean mPass_Correct = false;
mEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(s.toString()).matches()){emailWrittenCorrect(true);}
    else {emailWrittenCorrect(false);}}});

mPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.lenght>0){passwordWrittenCorrect(true);}
        else {passwordWrittenCorrect(false);}}});

private passwordWrittenCorrect(boolean x){
    passwordEmailCheck(null,x);
}
private void emailWrittenCorrect(boolean x){
    passwordEmailCheck(x,null);
}
private passwordEmailCheck(boolean emailStat, boolean passwordStat){
    if(emailStat!=null){
        mEmail_Correct = emailStat;

    }
    if(passwordStat!=null){
        mPass_Correct = passwordStat
    }
    if(emailStat && passwordStat){
       //show button
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @Sami Kanafani and how can I compare both booleans.

Comment: which 2 booleans you mean?

Comment: I mean the passwordWrittenCorrect and emailWrittenCorrect values, I need to check if the two values have true boolean or false, If the both booleans are true then the signin btn will be light and if not it will be dark, do you got it brother.

Comment: Sorry for late brother, anyway thanks It works perfectly.